Enforce naming convention of useState destructured variables [foo, setFoo]?
When using the useState hook, typically the two destructured array variables take the form: foo and setFoo.
Some examples that deviate from this template are:
const [foo, setfoo] = useState();    
const [foo, updateFoo] = useState();    
const [foo, fooSetter] = useState();    

During code review, I would recommend the above examples be changed to:
const [foo, setFoo] = useState();    

Is there a way of statically checking (ESLint) for this situation?

Yes, via eslint-plugin-react
The rule you want is this one: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/hook-use-state.md
From the docs:

This rule checks whether the value and setter variables destructured from a React.useState() call are named symmetrically.

Correct example:
import React from 'react';
export default function useColor() {
  // useState call is destructured into value + setter pair whose identifiers
  // follow the [thing, setThing] naming convention
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState();
  return [color, setColor];
}

In your config:
...
"react/hook-use-state": [<enabled>, { "allowDestructuredState": <boolean> }]
...

If for some reason you didn't want to use a third-party plugin, the code is available to inspect, and you could write your own rule.
Definitely better than having to police it during code review :)
